# Sliding a fixed div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I looked at an example where you have an anchor and onclick event on that anchor shows a hidden div as shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/SW6Mv/6/

However I have want to have a fixed panel at the bottom of my page that spans from one side of browser to another. Basically 100% width like this:
[image]

And when I press the button (half circle) the panel slides out.
[image]

However since my panel is fixed to the bottom of the page with:

```
#panel {
  position: fixed;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  z-index:1000;
  width:100%;
  background:#FFFFFF;
}
```

Slide out from jquery wont work. The main problem is since this is fixed to the bottom even if i can slide a second div up the main div is always over the top of it while it should have slided up. How can I get my div to stick to the bottom of the page but when pressed on button it slides up as second div appears bellow it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

below example code can help you. checkout the jsfiddle code.
Example code: http://jsfiddle.net/Q3yR8/1/

HTML Code:

```
<section id="header-bar" class="txt-highlight-color bg-color bg-pattern">
  <span id="close-bar" class="hide-bar">close button</span>
</section>
```

CSS Code:

```
#header-bar {position:fixed; bottom:0; left:0; width:200px; background-color:grey; height:50px;}
#close-bar { position:absolute; top:-20px; background:red; color:white;}
```

JS Code

```
var speed = 300;
        $('#close-bar').on('click', function(){

            var $$ = $(this);

            if( $$.is('.hide-bar') ){
                $('#header-bar').animate({bottom:-50}, speed);
                $$.removeClass('hide-bar')
            } else {
                $('#header-bar').animate({bottom:0}, speed);
                $$.addClass('hide-bar')
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You could set the bottom attribute to -100px (for example) to hide the element and then, use [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) to display it:

```
$('.circle').on('click', function(){
    $('#panel').animate({bottom: '100px'});
});
```